# XQuery on 2005 and SQLSM2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xquery

If You run this script on sql server 2008, works fine.

```
declare @tab table(
id_emp int,
FIL_ROT_WID xml
)

insert into @tab
select 0, '<xml></xml>'

declare @xml_rot_widget xml
set @xml_rot_widget = '<ati id="1123" val="new()" />'

update @tab
set FIL_ROT_WID.modify('insert sql:variable("@xml_rot_widget")
                    as last
                    into (/xml)[1]')
where id_emp = 0

select * from @tab
```

But Im using SQL Server 2005 with SQLSMS2008 and this scripts works fine too. But with the same level of databse em SQLSMS2005 I receive the following error:

```
XQuery: SQL type 'xml' is not supported in XQuery.
```

Im already solve the problem, but my question is:
How to configure the SQLSMS2008 to run script and parse them for DB 2005?

Ah, **Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Script for server version**
does not work. It keep running like 2008.

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote But Im using SQL Server 2005 with SQLSMS2008

There is no way this script would run on SQL 2005 no matter what version of Management Studio  you were using.  You must have been connected to the SQL 2008 server?  Use

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

to doublecheck if you're not sure of the version.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1765.0 (Intel X86)   Feb  2 2011 18:45:52   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

But the database compatibility level is 90 (2005)

Comment: So does that mean you're going to mark my answer then?  Thanks!

Comment: Your question maybe, but mine... So I can write any code that run only in 2008 wharever database compatibility level is?

Comment: As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186472(v=sql.105).aspx "Features new to a version cannot be scripted for earlier versions."